# Android: Progress Dialog shows a black screen

Tags: java, android

This is my code that am I using to implement a ProgressDialog when a camera fired and photo taken.

```
public void onPhotoTaken() {

        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Please wait...", true);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

On clicking on the save button of my android device, instead of displaying the Progress Dialog, it displays a black screen. Please what could be wrong.

Comment: Please clarify. Does the entire screen go black; or is it the dialog that appears that is black.

Comment: have you given any custom styles/themes for dialog

Comment: `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` try this theme in activity

Comment: The entire screen goes black

Comment: @Sud: Please can you be more elaborate on the comment above. It looks vague to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember when it comes to [Progress dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is that you should run it in a separate thread. If you run it in your UI thread you'll see no dialog.

If you are new to [Android Threading](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) then you should learn about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Which helps you to implement [painless Threads](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html).

Sample code:

```
private class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        ProgressDialog asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(IncidentFormActivity.this);
        String typeStatus;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //set message of the dialog
            asyncDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loadingtype));
            //show dialog
            asyncDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            //don't touch dialog here it'll break the application
            //do some lengthy stuff like calling login webservice

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //hide the dialog
            asyncDialog.dismiss();

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

}
```

Good luck.

**EDIT**

The method `show()` must be called from the User-Interface (UI) thread, while `doInBackground()` runs on different thread which is the main reason why AsyncTask was designed.

You have to call show() either in `onProgressUpdate()` or in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but I am having this error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: I will raise a new ticket while posting my complete code

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me just using your ProgressDialog line of code so the problem must be elsewhere but you can try:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
dialog.setTitle("Loading");
dialog.show();
```